# How to close Object Spy of HP UFT(12.02) using vbscript

Tags: object, vbscript, hp-uft, spy

We are using UFT for automation testing and have our own framework to invoke the Uft and load the scripts.
But if by chance Object spy is open UFT gives an error " the program is waiting for another user.." 
Can any one help to close object spy ( if it is open) using vb scripts commands

Comment: Are you saying that when you open UFT, Object spy is open somehow ? Or if user working on UFT leaves the Object spy open, then UFT cant start the executions (using programs) after that ?

Answer (score 0):

Object Spy is part of the UFT.exe process - maybe you could just use a WMI query to check if it exists before you invoke it and kill it if so?

```
Option Explicit
Dim objWMIService, objProcess, colProcess
Dim strComputer, strProcessKill 
strComputer = "."
strProcessKill = "'UFT.exe'" 

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 

Set colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = " & strProcessKill )

For Each objProcess in colProcess
    objProcess.Terminate()
Next 
WScript.Echo "Just killed process " & strProcessKill & " on " & strComputer
```

Or are you saying that you open UFT programmatically and Object Spy is opening on its own somehow?

Comment: Actualy the scenerio is as follows : i have opened UFT after that i was using object spy and forgot to close it.. and then when i run my scripts it checks wethr UFT is opened or not.. if it is opened then it try to load the scripts into the UFT but as the object spy is opened the error message is displayed "progrme waiting for another user...

Comment: I don't think you can do anything with object spy open to close it programmatically - my solution above would still work, just kill and restart the application and you ensure that object spy isn't in the way...

Answer (score 0):

ObjectSpy will neither be running as a separate process nor a child process of UFT. You cannot terminate or close ObjectSpy alone programmatically. You should close/terminate UFT to close ObjectSpy. As Dave mentioned, you can use his script to close UFT or you can skip execution, as UFT is already opened. The choice is yours.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to send an escape key to UFT after activate it with his process number:

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process", , 48)
appid = 0
For Each objItem In colItems
    If objItem.Name = "UFT.exe" Then
        'Get UFT process Id
        appid = objItem.ProcessId
        'Activate UFT
        AppActivate appid
        'Send Escape key on UFT
        SendKeys "{ESC}"
        'Exit from for statement
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

It works on UFT12.02 and UFT12.54.